# Various Data Validation File I/O Practices with Arrays and Strings C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, validation

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
void NumberSummaryList(string);
void Validation(string);

int main()
{
string file = "";
cout << "Hello, what is the name of the number file that you would like to process, please don't forget to include .txt   " << "-For Example-   data.txt" << endl;
cin >> file;
try
{
    ifstream DataIn;
    DataIn.open(file);
    if (DataIn.is_open() == false)
    {
        throw 20;
    }
}
catch (int e)
{
    cout << "An error has occurred with opening the file." << endl;
}

NumberSummaryList(file);
Validation(file);
}

void NumberSummaryList(string file)
{
    ifstream DataIn;
    DataIn.open(file);
    const int NumbersArray = 100;
    int numbers[NumbersArray];
    int count;
    int x;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    float avg = 0;
    count = 0;



    while (!DataIn.eof())
    {
        DataIn >> numbers[count];
        count++;
    }
    x = count;

    DataIn.close();


    for (int count = 0; count < x; count++)
    {
        cout << numbers[count] << "\n";
    }

    min = numbers[0];
    max = numbers[0];

    for (int count = 0; count < x; count++)
    {
        temp = numbers[count];
        if (temp < min)
            min = temp;
        if (temp > max)
            max = temp;
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < x; count++)
    {
        sum += numbers[count];
    }

    avg = sum / x;

    ofstream OutData;
    OutData.open("listsummary.txt");

    cout << "The total of numbers read in the data file is " << x << endl;
    cout << "The average of all numbers in the data file is " << avg << endl;
    cout << "The max value of the data file is " << max << endl;
    cout << "The min value of the data file is " << min << endl;

    OutData << "The total of numbers read in the data file is " << x << endl;
    OutData << "The average of all numbers in the data file is " << avg << endl;
    OutData << "The max value of the data file is " << max << endl;
    OutData << "The min value of the data file is " << min << endl;

    OutData.close();
}

void Validation(string file)
{
    ifstream DataInStrings;
    DataInStrings.open(file);
    int count = 0;
    string stringarray[100];
    int intarray[100];
    int y = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
    {

        getline(DataInStrings, stringarray[count]);

        if (stringarray[count].length() > 5)
        {
            cout << "Error Found! The element in position " << count + 1 << " " << stringarray[count] << " is too long. Error Written." << endl;
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }


    for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
    {
        string CopyofArray;
        CopyofArray = stringarray[count];

        int intcopy = stoi(CopyofArray);

        if (intcopy < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error Found! The element in position " << count + 1 << " " << stringarray[count] << " is negative. Error Written." << endl;
        }
        else
        {

        }


    }




    for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
    {
        cout << stringarray[count] << "\n";
    }

    string ArrayCopy;
    ArrayCopy = stringarray[count];

    //if (isalpha(ArrayCopy))
    //{

    //}
    //else
    //{
    //  cout << "Alphabetical characters detected in the file, error written." << endl;
    //}


    DataInStrings.close();
}
```

Hey guys. This is a project for class that I am stuck on and struggling with. The goal is to validate some of the data inside of the file I load in, which should be numbers 1-100. My teacher has required me to write out errors if the file contains any alphanumericals, symbols like ? or /, if the length of the element is greater than 5, and if the number is negative.

The program is also supposed to display the contents of the file 1-100, find the max, min, average, and total of numbers read.

I have successfully read in the file, found the max,  min, average, and total of numbers read. I also have successfully programmed it to write out errors if a number is too long or if it is negative.

However, my trouble comes whenever the file contains either an alphanumerical or a symbol. The file simply won't load and the program won't function correctly if I try to test out putting a alphanumerical or symbol in the data file.

I tried rewriting the program to use getline at first and read in the strings, and then convert when needed. But it now has an issue of where the program will not compute after an alphanumerical is found.

I am here to ask for advice or some type of direction in the right way. My teacher had us write part of the program first, and then added in the data validation parts which angers me because it jumbles the whole thing up in different places.

I look forward to any... please and thanks guys!

Comment: Why are you validating the input after computing the summary? Also, why are you reading the file twice? Open the file once, read in the data to a `vector<int>` while validating, and pass the vector to a summary function.

Comment: I can't use vectors for this assignment. We haven't gotten to those yet. Me reading the file twice is an error on my own, but that is not causing the problem with alphabeticals and such. I tried making a new code and I ran into another issue where it would compute only until an alphabetical appeared. Thanks for the point!

Comment: `stoi(CopyofArray)` will throw an exception, you can catch that. Also, you are using fixed size arrays. You can pass that to a function at least.

Comment: how can I properly catch that? That is what I am trying to figure out.